# Text overlapping several facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart that I've constructed using (horizontal) facets:

```
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("alpha", "beta", "sqrt(x, y)"))
k <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point()
k + facet_grid(. ~ cyl2)
```

I'd like to add text to this plot. I understand how to add text using `geom_text` to an individual facet, but I'd like my text to cover multiple facets. Like this (done in Paint):

[image]

A within-`ggplot` version would be preferable, but even an option that annotates an image after export would work. (The final image will be in a pdf through `knitr`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may, for example, use

```
library(grid)
grid.text("This is not alpha", x = 0.7, y = 0.8)
```

[image]